# Converting multiple files using pdf2htmlEX

Tags: html, pdf, pdf-to-html, pdf2htmlex

How do you use pdf2htmlEX on multiple files or on a folder that contains pdf files?

I am able to convert single files just fine, but I obviously don't want to run a command 100 times for 100 files.

I couldn't find anything in the documentation and something like '*.pdf' doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option is using a script to do so:

1. Create an script and put this content: (for this example we call it `mypdf2html.sh`)
2. Put this content inside (notice that it deleted the previous folder)

   ```
   rm -rf html
   mkdir html

   for (( i=1; i<118; i++ ));
   do
       infile="apcPage"$i
       pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 $infile".pdf" ./html/$infile".html"
   done
   ```
3. Run the script `sh mypdf2html.sh`